# Android running project

Tags: android

Error:Could not read path 'F:\Uni data\Project Work\Android Coding\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\com\example\syedmujahid\etutor'.

> F:\Uni data\Project Work\Android Coding\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\com\example\syedmujahid\etutor

Comment: Are you able to access that directory manually under Windows explorer? Sounds like a directory permissions issue

Comment: i don't know i am the beginner i just added some classes extending from Fragment.....and when i run the project it gives error

Comment: Open Windows Explorer and put `F:\Uni data\Project Work\Android Coding\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug\com\example\syedmujahid\etutor` in the path bar. Do you get an error?

Comment: And what sort of drive is `F:`? A local drive? USB external drive? Or a network share?

Comment: yes it gives an error NOT ACCESSIBLE

Comment: no its a local drive

Comment: Then it's a general Windows problem, not an Android Studio one. Try checking the permissions of the directory and its parent directory, or try recreating the project in a different location.